# Storing pre-order traversal of a tree in vector

Tags: recursion, tree, traversal, tree-traversal

I was trying to store my pre order traversal in a vector.
First i tried this.

```
vector<int> s;
vector <int> preorder(Node* root)
{
  if(root==NULL)
  return s;  
  s.push_back(root->data);
  preorder(root->left);
  preorder(root->right);
  return s;
}
```

And it gave me wrong answer but later when i tried this

```
void pre(Node* root,vector<int>& s)
{
  if(root==NULL)
  return;  
  s.push_back(root->data);
  pre(root->left,s);
  pre(root->right,s);
}
vector <int> preorder(Node* root)
{
 vector<int> s;
 pre(root,s);
 return s;
}
```

I got correct answer.I am not getting why my first code was giving me WA.
(How can i do this in one function?)

Comment: Are you clearing your vector `s` after every call to the function in first code? You seem to be calling multiple times but `s` never gets cleared.

Comment: Why do i need to clear it,I mean push_back function for every node will be executed once why do i need to clear my vector? @Suparshva

Comment: By multiple calls I meant not in the recursion sense. You seem to be making multiple preorder calls outside of the function with different `root` argument. Also I am assuming `s` to be a global.

Comment: Ya s is global.In first code i only had a main function apart from this.
link to ques:https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/preorder-traversal/1

Comment: Cool then it seems you are not in control of the driver code to your function. The driver code might be calling your function multiple times.

Comment: You mean first code is not wrong,it would have worked if there were no multiplr calls in main? @Suparshva

Comment: yes, for multiple calls you should manage resetting and clearing vector `s` in your driver after using, or make a wrapper to clear state. I would prefer your 2nd code as it is much cleaner and easy to use.

Comment: The top function is not [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Computer_science_meaning). Call it multiple times on the same instance and your second call surprisingly winds up with stale state left in `s`. However, this doesn't show a [mcve] of how you're using it.